# Will this azure build pipeline yaml config work?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-pipelines

I have this yaml in my spring boot app

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
  - master

resources:
  - repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'c***************************64b'
  imageRepository: '*********************ecicd'
  containerRegistry: '**********************.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build and push stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - task: Maven@3
            displayName: 'Maven Clean Install'
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
              goals: 'clean install'
              options: '-DskipTests=true'  # You can adjust options based on your Maven build needs

          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
            inputs:
              command: buildAndPush
              repository: $(imageRepository)
              dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
              tags: |
                $(tag)
```

I have Docker file also configured I just wanna know if this will work or not?currently azure doesn't let me to run pipeline I created a request ,it'll take two busness days,so I need help will someone please tell if this is okay and will work?

I've tried to deploy and run but it gave parallel error so I sent a request to add the parallelism

Comment: You'll find out in two days.

Comment: It looks like you have some custom variables in your yaml, so even if I were willing to run and test this yaml for you, I'm missing key information. Two days have passed.  If you still lack parallelism and can't wait any longer, I also recommend using a self-hosted agent to solve the urgent problem as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are utilizing the free tier of Azure DevOps and are awaiting approval for your free parallel agent.

If you really cannot wait, I would recommend configuring a new self hosted agent pool that you can utilize for your testing purposes. This can be installed on your local machine if need be, but I would recommend creating it on a virtual machine or container.

Read about [self hosted agents here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#self-hosted-agents).

---